# Kotlin - Split string into new string

Tags: string, kotlin

I have a string that is a version number but I only need the last two digits of the string. I.e, `15.0.4571.1502` -> `4571.1502`. I can't seem to figure out an efficient way to do this in Kotlin.

`Code:`

```
version = "15.0.4571.1502"

var buildOne = version.split(".").toTypedArray()[2]
var buildTwo = version.split(".").toTypedArray()[3]

var new = "$BuildOne"."$BuildTwo"
```

`Error:`

```
The expression cannot be a selector (occur after a dot)
```

Comment: Use `var new = "$buildOne.$buildTwo"` instead.

Comment: This isn’t PHP…

Comment: Nitpick: I think you mean the last two _components_ (or numbers) of the string. The last two _digits_ of your example are `02`.

Answer (score 7):

You've written the dot outside of the string template, the following should work:

```kotlin
val new = "$BuildOne.$BuildTwo"
```

You can further simplify your solution, by making use of functions provided in the Kotlin standard library.

```kotlin
val version = "15.0.4571.1502"

val new = version
    .split(".")
    .takeLast(2)
    .joinToString(".")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
val version = "15.0.4571.1502"

val new = version.split('.').drop(2).joinToString(".")
// also possible:
// val new = version.split('.').takeLast(2).joinToString(".")

println(new)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another possible solution using List destructuring:

```kotlin
val version = "15.0.4571.1502"
val (_, _, buildOne, buildTwo) = version.split(".")
val new = "$buildOne.$buildTwo"
```